# How Validate a url in ant design using getfiledecoder

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd

I wish to implement ant design url validation. using of getfiledecoder how to do url validation.

```
 <Form.Item label={label}>
        {getFieldDecorator(fieldName, {
          initialValue: initialValue,
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              whitespace: true,
              message: errorMessage,
              defaultField: { type: 'url' },
            },
          ],
        })(<Input placeholder={placeholder} className={'form-item input-lg'} />)}
      </Form.Item>
```

I can't do that url validation

Answer (score 6):

Here is the rule for url.

```
rules: [
        {
            required: true,
            message: "This field is required."
        },
        {
            type: "url",
            message: "This field must be a valid url."
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code slightly to what they show in the examples of ant design here:
https://ant.design/components/form/

and for the type of validators here:

https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator#type

```
 <Form.Item label={label}>
   {getFieldDecorator(fieldName, {
     initialValue: initialValue,
     rules: [
       {
         required: true,
         whitespace: true,
         message: errorMessage,
         type: 'url',
       },
     ],
    })(<Input placeholder={placeholder} className={'form-item input-lg'} />)}
 </Form.Item>
```